# Custom UitableViewCell shows duplicate data for some rows of table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am facing a very strange issue with the custom UITableViewCell.

I have created a custom UITableViewCell using storyboard prototype cell.
The custom cell contains a textview for user input.
The table has 5 rows.

When i try to run the app and enter text in textview it works fine till row number 3 after that the textview of row numbers 4 & 5 gets automatically populated with row 1 & 2 data.

Can somebody please help me with this.

I want to add some more piece of information. I printed the cells in console and got the log as:

```
Data for row 0, <TableSampleApp.customcell: 0x7ff3c3c33570; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 375 301); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ff3c3c1aac0>>

Data for row 1, <TableSampleApp.customcell: 0x7ff3c3dd8a40; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 301; 375 301); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ff3c3dd85c0>>

Data for row 2, <TableSampleApp.customcell: 0x7ff3c3f12e10; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 602; 375 301); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ff3c3f12300>>

Data for row 3, <TableSampleApp.customcell: 0x7ff3c3c33570; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 903; 375 301); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ff3c3c1aac0>>

Data for row 4, <TableSampleApp.customcell: 0x7ff3c3dd8a40; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 1204; 375 301); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ff3c3dd85c0>>
```

As you can see here, the rows 0 & 3 and rows 1 & 4 are having same values for CALayer and TableSampleApp.customcell What could be the reason for this ?

This is the code for cellforRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "RiskAssessCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "questionCustomCell")
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("questionCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! QuestionCustomCell

    return cell
}
```

The custom cell has a textview in it. After i run the app and input text in textview, the same text gets replicated in cell 3 & 4.

Comment: set tag value for textView in cellForRow method and while changing text  update dataArray

Comment: I think you might have a bug in your code. I also use UITableViewCell and has exactly 5 rows and all of it works good...:-)

Comment: UITableViewCell is reused.

Comment: @childrenOurFuture i am unable to use if cell==nil in swift. please suggest something to resolve this issue

Comment: Since cells are been reused, I think you will have to store all the inputs and reset each textView's text using the stored info and the row number

Comment: are you updating your content inside cellForRowAtIndexPath? and if you are facing issue after scroll. Try to write below code after you configure your cell for (UIView* view in [cell.contentView subviews])
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

Comment: `public func registerNib(nib: UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)` or 
`public func registerClass(cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)`, and you don't need to use if cell == nil, the system will create a new one for you.

Comment: Can I see how you are populating the data? Also, include the code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Create cell with using below code,

```
let cellIdentifier = "CustomCell"
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as! yourCustomCell
```